# Analyticity of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $V$ be a real finite-dimensional pre-Hilbert space and $A_j \colon V\to V$ be linear transformations, where $A_0$ is invertible. For $s\ge 0$, we define that $A_s=\sum_{j=0}^k s^j A_j$.

I want to show that, in a neighborhood of $0$, $A_s$ is invertible and the map $s\mapsto A_s$ is analytic. How is it showed?

Comment: The set of invertible linear mapping is open.

Comment: A finite-dimensional real or complex inner product space is automatically complete. So $V$ is a Hilbert space, not just pre-Hilbert.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.